# Bottom overflowed error even using SingleChildScrollview

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a SingleChildScrollView to scroll in my app view but I'm having an overflowed error. I tried the property "resizeToAvoidBottomInset", I was returning the SingleChildScrollView as body from Scaffold and I chaged by ListView too, but the error continued. How can I solve this?

```
return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: 
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: Get.height * 0.04),
                    width: Get.width,
                    height: Get.height * 0.2,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      'Evolução Fonoaudiologia',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: Get.height * 0.8,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: Get.width * 0.03, right: Get.width * 0.03),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: Get.height * 0.2,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: kLightGreyColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        // My form widgets like in the screenshot
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        )));
```

[image: Picture of bottom overflowed error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrap the column with SingleChildScrollView:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
```